# How to prove b | a iff remainder = 0

Tags: elementary-number-theory, divisibility

I am trying to find a way to prove that $b|a$ if and only if the remainder of $a$ divided by $b$ is $0$.

So far this is what I have:

If $r$ is the remainder of $a$ divided by $b$, this means $a=bq+r$. Subsequently, if $r=0$ then $a=bq$ which means $b|a$ by definition.

What I can't figure out is how to prove the if and only if part. I'm not sure if its better to start from $b|a$ and prove that $r=0$ or try to prove that if $r>0$ then $b \nmid a$. Either way I have had trouble with the steps to make the proper conclusion.

Comment: What is the def of $b|a$ ?

Comment: The def of $b|a$ is there exists some integer $k$ such that $a=bk$.

Comment: **Hint** $ $ Use the *uniqueness* of the remainder.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the other direction, you have $b|a$, and you want to prove that the reminder $r$ is 0.

$b|a$, therefore $a = bq$ for some $q$.
On the other hand, $a = bp + r$ for some $p$ and some $0 \le r < b$.

Therefore, $bq = bp + r$, so $b(q-p) = r$.
If $q < p$, then $r < 0$, contradiction. On the other hand, if $q > p$, then $r > b$, again contradiction. So we have $q=p$, therefore $r=0$.

Also, if you have already proven the uniqueness of the reminder (which goes pretty much the same as what I have above), you can simply show that 0 works as reminder, so that must be it.

Comment: You're essentially duplicating the proof of the *uniqueness* of the remainder. If this is already know (as is common) then one should simply invoke it rather than duplicate it.

Comment: Thanks, this helped me understand why the uniqueness of the remainder is the key. I did already have that as given/proved but seeing it connected directly is helpful.

Comment: @raznbagel Uniqueness theorems [often provide powerful tools for proving equalities,](https://math.stackexchange.com/search?q=user%3A242+uniqueness+powerful) so they are one of the first things one should try when they are available.